# User friendly back-uping system - autoadding script to crontable

Tags: php, apache, cron

I want to make user-friendly back-uping system. User will enable the option of auto-back of database, and the script should add itself to crontable, to periodically make a copy of database. Is there anyway to implement that kind of thing (I mean auto-signing to crontable by  PHP script)? I tried Google searching, but didn't see anything revelant.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to do it the following way:

1) use a (main) php file as a cronjob that looks into a folder to check for each file in that folder containing for example a json code with details of what to backup.

This main php file opens all the files and runs the backup preference of that dynamically created file (via the control panel or whatever these users got access to).